# add prefix to all files and folders in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How can I add a prefix or a suffix to all files/ folders in Google Drive using Google Script. The objective is that whenever a users needs to be deleted to add a suffix to all files and folders and transfer to another user so that the documents of the user can easily be tracked at a later stage.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The [File.setName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setName(String)) method in the Drive Service will do what you want. I'd be happy to help further if you post a sample of your code.

Comment: Hi Paul, I am not a programmer and usually rely on the scripts available on the net / forums etc for my day to day work. Hence do not have a code available.